# Cannot save value using ajax in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using laravel and trying to save data using post through ajax but data is not saved in database. I'm getting following error: jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/admin/products/attributes/add 500 (Internal Server Error). My code is as follows:

> view:

```
<script>
     $("#add_attributes_info").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/admin/products/attributes/add',
            data: $('#frmattributes').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log('success'+msg);
              }
        });
        });
</script>
 <form action="#" id="frmattributes" method="POST">
            <h3 class="tile-title">Add Attributes To Product</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="values">Select an value <span class="m-l-5 text-danger"> *</span></label>
                        <select id="attribute_values" name="value" class="form-control custom-select mt-15">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="quantity" type="number" id="quantity"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="price">Price</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="price" type="text" id="price"/>
                        <small class="text-danger">This price will be added to the main price of product on frontend.</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="add_attributes_info">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

> Controller:

```
  public function addAttribute(Request $request)
    {
        $productAttribute = ProductAttribute::create($request->data);

        if ($productAttribute) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Product attribute added successfully.']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Something went wrong while submitting product attribute.']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your `storage/logs` for the `.log` file that contains a full error, rather then just 500.

Comment: @nakov: In log i'm getting this  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, null given,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the controller, change the `$request->data` with :

```
$productAttribute = ProductAttribute::create($request->all());
```

or also check what the request contains, before creating you can check using:

```
dd($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
$productAttribute = ProductAttribute::create($request->all());
```

However you should keep in mind this is very risky without validation.

You should add input validation and then use:

```
$productAttribute = ProductAttribute::create($request->validated());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$request->all();`

```
  public function addAttribute(Request $request)
    {
        $productAttribute = ProductAttribute::create($request->all());

        if ($productAttribute) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Product attribute added successfully.']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Something went wrong while submitting product attribute.']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PS : I made some changes to get it works

Hope this help

```
<head>

    <title></title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajaxSetup({

            headers: {

                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

            }

        });

        function submitForm() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '../admin/products/attributes/add',
                data: $('#frmattributes').serialize(),
                success: function(msg) {
                    console.log('success' + msg);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="frmattributes">
        <h3 class="tile-title">Add Attributes To Product</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="values">Select an value <span class="m-l-5 text-danger"> *</span></label>
                    <select id="attribute_values" name="value" class="form-control custom-select mt-15">

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="quantity" type="number" id="quantity" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="price">Price</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="price" type="text" id="price" />
                    <small class="text-danger">This price will be added to the main price of product on frontend.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="add_attributes_info" type="button" onclick="submitForm()">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```